# trackRevisions (aka track changes) missing from ooxml data

Tags: javascript, office-js, cpu-word

I'm trying to use office.js to determine whether or not track changes has been enabled.  There doesn't appear to be an office.js API call to fetch this setting, but thought I could use the getOoxml method to acquire the setting.

I'm using the following code to retrieve the xml string data representation of the document

```
   Word.run(context => {
      const ooxml = context.document.body.getOoxml();
      return context.sync().then(() => {
         console.log(ooxml.value);
      })
   });
```

This code works in Word Online as I'm able to locate <w:trackRevisions/> in the xml string data.  However the same is not true for the desktop version of MSWord.  Whilst the above call successfully returns the xml string data for the document, the <w:trackRevisions/> xml element is curiously absent, even when track changes is enabled and the document is saved.

More curiously, if I unzip this docx and locate the settings.xml file I can see that <w:trackRevisions/> xml element is present under the <w:settings> node, whilst at the same time curiously absent from the getOoxml api call data.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there another way to determine whether or not track changes has been enabled.